# Rails custom field in to_json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have this code:

```
@locations = @list.all.to_json(:root => false,
                 :only => [:author,:lat,:long,:text])
```

It works great and is exactly what I want. But now I want to add to the fields an url for the show page of each entry.

So it would be like:

```
[{
   "author:"blabla",
   "lat":blabla,
   "long":blabla,
   "text":"blabla",
   "url":"url for show page"
 }]
```

I've tried merge option but it doesn't add anything or throw any errors.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please mark an answer as accepted if it helped to solve your problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to phts I was able to get a solution:

I defined the method in the model

```
def url
    "/url/to/page/#{id}"
end
```

And in the options i added:

```
:methods => :url
```

And it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you add this field to a model (or whatever you called `@list.all`). For example:

```
class MyModel

  def url
    "/url/to/page/#{id}"
  end

end
```

and in the controller just add a field to `only` array

```
@locations = @list.all.to_json(:root => false,
             :only => [:author,:lat,:long,:text,:url])
```

Comment: I corrected your answer. But yours did help me find the right way

Answer (score 0):

You have an array after to_json, so there is no `#merge`:

```
@locations = @list.all.to_json(:root => false, :only => [:author,:lat,:long,:text]).collect do |l|
  l.merge( {text: 'mytext',url: 'myurl'} )
end
```

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry, writing  from a phone.